# Why are my values offsetting when I calculate a new variable in SAS?

Tags: date, sas

I am trying to use the YEAR() function in SAS to pull the year from a date formatted in MMDDYY10. However, when I calculate the new column called "year" all the values are offset by one row.

For example, I want:

```
    Date          Year

    12/31/2014       2014
    06/25/2007       2007
```

But I am getting:

```
   Date         Year
  12/31/2014       . 
  06/25/2007      2014
     .           2007


 Data Clinic2;
   format datebp MMDDYY10.;
   year = YEAR(datebp);
   set Clinic; 
   run;
```

Answer (score 2):

The order of the statements is important.  Your program is calculating the year and then reading the value of DATEBP from the dataset.  Since YEAR is not in the source dataset the value of year is not changed by the SET statement.

That is why the first observation has a missing value for YEAR, no value of DATEBP has been read yet.  The reason the rest of the values of YEAR are not missing is because SAS does not reset variables sourced from input dataset to missing before starting the next iteration of the data step.  So for the 2nd, 3rd, etc iteration you are calculating YEAR from the DATEBP value that was read on the previous iteration.  Then you replace that value of DATEBP with the value from the current observation being read by the SET statement.

Answer (score 1):

change it to below code. your set statement has come to first from the data has to be read to do calculation. If you keep variable before the set statement then your new variable initialization starts with missing value and then set statement is read.

```
 Data Clinic2;
  set Clinic;
   year = YEAR(datebp);
  run;
```

let us try understanding using sashelp.class. 
Variable initialization has started even before reading the data to missing value.

```
/* wrong way*/
 data want;
age1 = age+5;
 set sashelp.class;
 run;
```

[image]

Variable initialization has started even after reading the data and not assigned to missing value.

```
 /* correct way*/
data want;
set sashelp.class;
 age1 = age+5;
run;
```

[image]